# Приходят пустые поля phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Почему то приходит пустые поля в письме.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['username'];
$phone = $_POST['userphone'];
$vacancy = $_POST['vacancy'];

include('class.phpmailer.php');
    $email = new PHPMailer();
    $email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $email->From      = '*********';
    $email->FromName  = '****';
    $email->Subject   = 'Новый отклик на вакансию';
    $email->Body =  "Имя: $name\nНомер телефона: $phone\nВакансия: $vacancy";
    $email->AddAddress( '*********' );
if (isset($_FILES['resume']) &&
    $_FILES['resume']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $email->AddAttachment($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['resume']['name']);
}
        return $email->Send();
?>
```

в форме указан метод post, multipart/form-data.
Использую CF7 (он настроен на отправку в amocrm, а мне необходимо на почту чтобы приходила заявка с этой формы),вот код формы :

```
<form action="/vakansii/#wpcf7-f568-o2" method="post" class="wpcf7-form vacancy-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="568" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.7" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="ru_RU" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f568-o2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="4c48550b86" />
    </div>
    <div class="popup-title">
      Отклик на вакансию
    </div>
    <p class="popup-description">Укажите Ваши данные, мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время</p>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap username">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Введите имя" />
      </span>
      <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap userphone">
        <input type="tel" name="userphone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Введите телефон" />
      </span>
      <label>Прикрепить резюме<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap resume">
        <input type="file" name="resume" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" aria-invalid="false" />
      </span></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="vacancy" value="Привет, мир!" />
        <div class="btn-vacancy-form">
            <span class="red-btn">
                <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
</form>
```

Вот скрипт передающий поля обработчику:

```
$(".vacancy-form").submit(function() { return false; });

    $(".wpcf7-submit").on("click", function(){

            var form = document.forms.commentForm;

            var formData = new FormData(form);  

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "send.php");

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if(xhr.status == 200) {
                        data = xhr.responseText;
                        if(data == "true") {
                            $(".sending").replaceWith("<p>Принято!<p>");
                        } else {
                            $(".sending").replaceWith("<p >Ошибка! Обновите страницу...<p>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.send(formData);

            });
```

Comment: а пробовали вывести print_r($_POST) перед всем остальным, перейдя вручную.

Comment: class.phpmailer.php лежит в этой же папке?

Comment: ничего не выводит. да, рядом лежит.

Comment: Пустой массив? array(); ? У вас включено отображение ошибок?

Comment: Покажите код формы

Comment: показал выше, да пустой